# Is there any performance benefit capturing only needed variables in scope in a lambda expression with [&var] instead of capturing all with [&]?

Tags: c++

Or does it make any difference at all, because unused references are optimized away by the compiler?

> "When a lambda definition is executed, for each variable that the lambda captures, a clone of that variable is made (with an identical name) inside the lambda. These cloned variables are initialized from the outer scope variables of the same name at this point."

ref: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/lambda-captures/.

I suppose the clone takes time also?

Comment: The quote you cite refers to captures *by value*; captures *by reference* work differently.

Comment: Interesting that you think capturing explicitly would perform worse than "capturing all" implicitly.  With explicit capture, there is a risk of capturing something that is unreferenced within the body of the lambda -- which is the only opportunity for worse performance that I can think of at the moment.  It's about what you use or do not use in the body of the lambda.  The capturing is about _scope_, and making sure a symbol selects the intended value or variable.

Comment: your reference isnt the worst source, but usually cppreference is the one closest to the wording in the standard. Sometimes harder to read but often more accurate https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: [&] doesn't "capture all" it captures (by referrence) only those things you actually use in the body of your lambda.

Comment: Performance is nice, but if the program is going to go the distance and last a long time, the code needs to express intent well, and capturing everything doesn't do that well, except in cases where you really do mean to capture everything.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes this seems to be the correct answer

Comment: @Wyck Wouldn't you hope that any compiler worth its GPL optimizes unused captures away, just as it would ignore unused local variables!?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Oh absolutely!  I was trying to convey that it's obvious (to me) that `[=]` doesn't copy everything -- only what is used in the lambda body.  But less obvious that `[=foo]` doesn't copy `foo` if `foo` is unused in the lambda body (because it seems like you're almost asking for it to be). And therefore it's surprising (to me) to be of the opinion that the automatic "only capture what is used" (`=`) could perform worse than "please explicitly capture these things" (`=foo`)  (And, yes, I realize we're talking about `[&]` but same concept applies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the compilers I am familiar with implement closures is to effectively create a struct of all the captures and pass a pointer to the struct as a parameter to the function. The compiler will only add to the struct those captures explicitly listed, and in the case of the general capture, only those visible variables that are actually used in the body of the lambda.

So in short, explicitly listing the captures for a lambda is possibly a pessimization since it might copy more values than are strictly necessary. The optimizer can and does eliminate some unused captures or change them from by-reference to by-value when it can do so.

By the time the optimizer has done its job you're unlikely to notice any performance penalty even in tight inner loops. You are better off making your captures explicit because it expresses intent and that's the expensive part of software development.